# Rules for factoring complex polynomials and the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to analyze a proof of The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra of Complex Polynomials and more or less rewrite it in layman's terms with a bit more explanation however I am having trouble understanding one part of the proof:

---

LEMMA 1. Let Q(z) be a nonzero complex polynomial. There exists a number
$d > 0$ such that $Q(a)=0$  implies $Q(a + d)\neq0$.
Proof. From the theorem about factoring polynomials, it follows that $Q(z) = 0$ has
a finite number of solutions. The assertion of the lemma follows by taking $d$ to be a
positive number that is less than the distance between any two distinct roots of $Q$. This proves Lemma 1.

---

Could anyone explain this a bit more concretely with a little more detail?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing a graphical interpretation of what they are saying since it just says d is "some positive number" I thought maybe it had to do with the multiplicity of the roots but I'm not sure

Comment: The picture I was thinking of was just a blank piece of paper with finitely many dots on it, representing the $n$ roots of your polynomial of degree $n$.